# Can users be added with Google search console python code?

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def add_site_owner(api_key, site_url, owner_email):
    # API'ya erişim için yetkilendirme
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('your_service_account_key.json',
                                                                   ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'])
    service = build('webmasters', 'v3', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

    # Site sahibini ekleme işlemi
    request = service.sites().addOwner(siteUrl=site_url, ownerUserEmail=owner_email)
    response = request.execute()

    print("Site sahibi başarıyla eklendi:")
    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
    SITE_URL = "YOUR_SITE_URL"
    OWNER_EMAIL = "site_owner@example.com"  # Eklenecek site sahibinin e-posta adresi

    add_site_owner(API_KEY, SITE_URL, OWNER_EMAIL)
```

Can users be added with Google search console python code?  This code did not work. Help please

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Resource' object has no attribute 'addOwner'
  File "C:\Users\cem\Desktop\python programlar\cpanele gir sub domain oluştur\from googleapiclient.py", line 11, in add_site_owner
    request = service.sites().addOwner(siteUrl=site_url, ownerUserEmail=owner_email)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\cem\Desktop\python programlar\cpanele gir sub domain oluştur\from googleapiclient.py", line 22, in <module>
    add_site_owner(API_KEY, SITE_URL, OWNER_EMAIL)
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'addOwner'
```